# What are my options to supply configuration settings to an Azure Function and how to secure them?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to supply a few environment-related configuration settings (such as passwords and Connection Strings) to my Azure function.

What are my options to supply such settings to my Azure Function and how to secure settings such as Passwords?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated app service or are you using the comsumption based host? Anyway, this might solve the question about secrets: https://david-obrien.net/2016/09/azure-functions-secrets/. And if it has its own app service look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these settings are consumed by your function bindings (triggers/input/output), the way to supply these settings is by setting environment variables on the app via Web App Application Settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings

If they are not used in `function.json` properties, then you can use other key management solutions such as Azure Key Vault within your function code.

Comment: Here is example how to get app settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#environment-variables